# Axios and App GET/POST requests to external api

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am new to axios and nodejs/express. Axios calls were made from the React component files themselves, and I decided to move them to a file called "user.service.js" to learn best practices. However they don't work how I expect them to. The following are two scenarios.

For a GET request, this works:
user.service.js:

```
class UserService {
    getDevices() {
        return axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE + "/userDevices", {
            params: {
                access_token: user.access_token,
              }
        });
    }
}
export default new UserService();
```

server.js:

```
app.get('/userDevices', (req, res) => {
    console.log("grabbing user list of available devices");

    axios.get(api_url + "/api/devices", {
        headers: 
        { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + req.query.access_token }
    }
    ).then((response) => {
        res.send({ devices: response.data });
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('failed to grab user devices');
        res.send('error');
    });
});
```

But this (changing the getDevices function in user.service.js and the header in server.js) doesn't:
user.service.js:

```
    getDevices() {
        return axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE + "/userDevices", {
            headers: {
                authorization: 'Bearer +' user.access_token,
              }
        });
    }
```

server.js:

```
app.get('/userDevices', (req, res) => {
    console.log("grabbing user list of available devices");

    axios.get(api_url + "/api/devices", {
        headers: req.headers.authorization
    }
    ).then((response) => {
        res.send({ devices: response.data });
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('failed to grab user devices');
        res.send('error');
    });
});
```

For a POST request, this doesn't work at all:
user.service.js:

```
class UserService()
{
    addDevice(eid, deviceType, configGroup, name, ip, tenantID) {
        return axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE + "/addDevice", {
            params :{
                eid: eid,
                deviceType: deviceType,
                configGroup: configGroup, 
                name: name,
                ip: ip, 
                tenantID: tenantID,
                access_token: user.access_token
            }
        });
    }
}
export default new UserService();
```

server.js:

```
app.post('/addDevice', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Adding new device');
   
    const device = [{
        "eid": req.body.eid,
        "fields": {
            "deviceType": req.body.deviceType,
            "configGroup": req.body.configGroup,
            "field:name": req.body.name,
            "field:ip": req.body.ip
        }
    }];
 
    axios.post(api_url + "/api/devices", device, {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + req.query.access_token,
            "X-Tenant-ID": req.body.tenantID,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"        
        }
    }).then((response) => {
        res.send({ status: response.data.message });
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('failed to add device', err);
        res.send({ status: 'error' });
    });
});
```

Printing "req.body.tenantID" is undefined. I create a new instance of this class in my React component, and other functions do work. I suspect my calls to "req.body" are not correct, but I'm at a loss right now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's hard to follow this code, or what the problem is exactly, but `'Bearer +' user.access_token` is a typo: `'Bearer ' + user.access_token`. The request seems totally different between the inlined and external versions -- are you intending a straight refactor with the same functionality or are you also changing the request? Where's `user.access_token` coming from? `req.body.tenantID` being undefined seems like a request problem, not to do with the axios code at all. You might want to show your POST request.